# Jsoup getElementById throws a NullPointerException only on GCloud VM

Tags: jsoup, gcloud

The jar run without errors on my local machine but when I load it on a Gcloud VM, Jsoup getElementById throws a NPE.

Document `doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();` works properly on both machines and I can print the `doc`, but

```
Element section = doc.getElementById("my_id");
```

throws NPE on VM (I verified section is actually null), I don't understand why.

*OpenJDK11 is installed on VM*

Comment: If you print `doc.toString()` or save it to file do you get the same result in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the output were different because the VM connected to the global domain and the local to the Italian one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After printed `doc` as suggested in comment section, I noticed that the VM connected to a different web page (based on geo position) than the one in my local machine.